# Moving files/directories older than 7 days

Tags: bash

I have this code to find files/directories older than 7 days, then execute a mv. However I realise I need a different command for directories and files. `-type` also does not support `fd` - a manual says it only supports one character.

```
find /mnt/third/bt/uploads/ -type f -mtime +7 -exec mv {} /mnt/third/bt/tmp/ \;
```

How do I move both files and directories >7d into `/mnt/third/bt/tmp/` whilst keeping the same structure they had in `/mnt/third/bt/uploads/`?

Thanks

Comment: "However I realise I need a different command for directories and files" Now, maybe I am not getting something important here, but why? The     mv     syntax is the same for directories and files.

Comment: What do you do with an old directory containing a new file? What about a new directory containing an old file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMHO, this is a non-trivial problem to do it correctly - at least for me :). I will be happy, if someone more experienced post a better solution.

The script: (must have a GNU find, if your "find" is GNU-version change the gfind to find)

```
FROMDIR="/mnt/third/bt/uploads"
TODIR="/mnt/third/bt/tmp"
tmp="/tmp/movelist.$$"

cd "$FROMDIR"
gfind . -depth -mtime +7 -printf "%Y %p\n" >$tmp
sed 's/^. //' < $tmp | cpio --quiet -pdm "$TODIR"

while read -r type name
do
    case $type in
    f) rm "$name";;
    d) rmdir "$name";;
    esac
done < $tmp
#rm $tmp
```

Explanation:

- find everything what you want move (will copy first and delete after) and store it in a tmpfile (find)
- copy a list of things from a tmpfile to the new place (cpio)
- and finally remove old files and dirs - based on a list from a tmpfile (while...)

The script does not handling symbolic links, fifo files, etc., and will print zilion errors at the deleting directories what **are old, but they're not empty** (contain new files or subdirs)

**DRY RUN first!** :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to search for both files and directories, find [supports boolean operators](http://www.go2linux.org/linux/2011/02/how-use-find-boolean-operators-and-or-not-903).

Comment: consider adding an example to your answer.