# Removing old folders in bash backup script

Tags: bash, backup

I have a bash script that rsyncs files onto my NAS to the directory below:

```
mkdir /backup/folder_`date +%F`
```

How would I go about writing a cleanup script that removes directories older than 7 days old based upon the date in directories name?

Comment: Find out what day it is, then use pattern matching or regular expressions on the directory name

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963859/moving-files-directories-older-than-7-days and www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-general-1/bash-script-to-remove-files-older-than-3-days-462290/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash

shopt -s extglob

OLD=$(exec date -d "now - 7 days" '+%s')

cd /backup || exit 1 ## If necessary.

while read DIR; do
    if read DATE < <(exec date -d "${DIR#*folder_}" '+%s') && [[ $DATE == +([[:digit:]]) && DATE -lt OLD ]]; then
        echo "Removing $DIR."  ## Just an example message. Or we could just exclude this and add -v option to rm.
        rm -ir "$DIR"  ## Change to -fr to skip confirmation.
    fi
done < <(exec find -maxdepth 1 -type d -name 'folder_*')

exit 0
```

We could actually use more careful approaches like `-rd $'\0'`, `-print0` and `IFS=` but I don't think they are really necessary this time.

Answer (score 0):

Create a list of folders with the pattern you want to remove, remove the folders you want to keep from the list, delete everything else.

Answer (score 0):

How about a simple find:

`find /backup -name 'folder_*' -type d -ctime 7 -exec rm -rf {} \;`